# There are just two possibilities for matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $p$ be a prime number and consider  the  *-ring $M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$, the $n\times n$ matrices over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ (the involution is just the transpose).

Q. True or false: Every matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is orthogonal or completely  non-orthogonal!

$\bullet$ A matrix $A$ is called orthogonal if $A^*A=AA^*=id$.

$\bullet$  A matrix $A$ is called completely non-orthogonal if there is **no** non-zero projection $P$ such that $PA=AP$ and $PA^*A=PAA^*=P$.

Comment: Note that a matrix which is unitary, is also completely non-unitary. (Take P=Id).

Comment: What do you mean by the "field ${\mathbb Z}_p$"? The finite field of $p$ elements? This is usually written ${\mathbb F}_p$.

Comment: The standard terminology is "orthogonal". There exist a notion of unitary matrix over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ making use of a Galois involution. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @Corbennick I first misread as you: completely non-orthogonal means there is **no** $P$. So certainly orthogonal and completely non-orthogonal are not compatible.

Comment: So, $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is neither orthogonal nor completely non-orthogonal (just pick $P=A$).

Comment: @YCor How about $A\in\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb F_p)$? That seems a more natural setting for the question, although admittedly not what the OP asked.

Comment: @JoeSilverman still a trivial exercise (for a field of at least of $\ge 4$ elements): $A=diag(1,s)$ for $s\neq 0,\pm 1$, $P=diag(1,0)$. For $p=2,3$, you can ask your computer.

Comment: @YCor  Thanks. Following your answer, I faced another one which I prefer to ask at a new post.